# How to rename and save files which are already on the list

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, save-as, datagridviewrow

my app has a function to read file names and display them in the first column one by one in the DataGridView. What I want to do is, if users type in new names in the second column next to its original name, and then press the 'save as' button, files get saved consequently as newly typed in names, according to the order of the list.

I didn't bind it with DB or something like that.

My guess is that if users click save as button, it calls the code of each newly named block, and bring that code to 'save as' function. But I have no idea how I could realize it. Maybe my guess is totally wrong; you could give some advice so that I can find a right way!

I kindly ask for you help!

Here's my code

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Word(*.docx)| *.docx|PPT(*.pptx)|*.pptx|PDF(*.pdf)|*.pdf|Alle Dateien(*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            string ndn = "";//neue Dateinamen
            bool umlaut, pdf, wasserzeichen;
            int kopien;
            

            
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    string[] selectedFiles = ofd.SafeFileNames;
                    for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(selectedFiles[i]);
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Dateinamen"].Value.ToString();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Neue Dateinamen"].Value.ToString();  // Here I tried to save values of new names
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Kopien"].Value.ToString();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Wasserzeichen"].Value.ToString();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Umlaut"].Value.ToString();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PDF"].Value.ToString();

      
                    }
                }
          
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Save as
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Word(*.docx)| *.docx|PPT(*.pptx)|*.pptx|PDF(*.pdf)|*.pdf|Alle Dateien(*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                }

            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: As currently written, button2_Click (sort of) populates the data grid with the found file names. For the functionality to save as new file, you obviously need a second button.

Comment: @KlausGütter  You're right, I do have that button, but since it's kinda empty I just didn't write it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I don't get the meanig of yout comment "// Here I tried to save values of new names". The user can enter the name only after you populated the table, or?

Comment: @KlausGütter I wanted to save each of the values of what the user entered as new names because I thought those values are gonna be needed. To enable the user to enter the name only after the table's populated is not my intention.

Comment: "what the user entered as new names": so when and where shall the user do this?

Comment: @If the user enters a new name on the DataGridView, the new name gets saved, and passes it to the value of 'new name' and then the value is to be displayed on the 'new name' row of DataGridView and the new file should be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code for the save button

```
private void SaveWithName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        string OldName = Path.Combine(FilesPath, dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        string NewName = Path.Combine(FilesPath, dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) ;
        System.IO.File.Copy(OldName, NewName);
    }
```

The variable FilesPath is a public string. This variable will contain the directory name where your selected files are. Look an example of the code for the button that reads the file list

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] selectedFiles = ofd.SafeFileNames;
            FilesPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);

            label1.Text = FilesPath;
            for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(selectedFiles[i]);
            }
        }
```

There you can see the line where the variable FilesPath is filled.

Comment: Dear @LFLJM, it is great that this post has been useful for you. Please, if you are satisfied, mark the post as the solution.